# how to change character encoding in mac?

Tags: html, macos, character-encoding

I just edited a .html file using Adobe Dreamweaver, the charset is gb2312 since it's a Chinese website, then I used TextMate to edit the file, after I save the file, it was changed into utf-8 since the version of TextMate I'm using doesn't support Chinese. Is there any way I change the charset back to gb2312?

Comment: try `iconv` http://www.fileformat.info/tip/linux/iconv.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Utilities -> Terminal and then sudo -s
then 
Use the following command

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t GB2312 oldfile.html > newfile.html
```

Change the charset in command accordingly.

OR

Mac has a file version system like TimeMachine. You can browse the previous versions of the file. See if mac saved the previous version of your file.

Comment: actually iconv doesn't support GB-2312, and I didn't set up Time Machine. But thanks a lot!

Comment: @vvv214 `iconv -l` includes GB2312, but you could also try `brew install recode; recode utf8..gb2312 input.txt`.